# Button reference issue Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, events, button

In `UITableViewCell` when I click on a button it cross references it with another `UITableViewCell` and reflects the same action in that one also. I am not getting the exact cell position on which i want to take action. Let me know if any solutions to solve this problem.

Thanks.

```html
//===============tableview load home page point type U set image Like ===========

 NSString *nul  =[[arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"point_type"];
        if ([nul isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            cell.lblpointtype.text = @"Null";
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lblpointtype.text = @"U";
            [cell.btnlike setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_good_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


//=================Like button click event source code==========================

-(IBAction)like:(UIButton *)sender
{
    
   CustomTableViewCell *clickedCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonIndexPath = [Mytableview indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    
    int selectedIndexPath = clickedButtonIndexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"SelectedIndexPath: %d",selectedIndexPath);
    
    
   postid = [[arry objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath]objectForKey:@"post_id"];
    NSLog(@"userInfo : %@", postid);
    postimageid = [[arry objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath]objectForKey:@"post_image_id"];
    NSLog(@"userInfo : %@", postimageid);
    
   // cell.lblpointtype.text =[[arry objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath]objectForKey:@"point_type"];
//    NSLog(@"point type: %@",cell.lblpointtype);
    //cell.btnlike.tag = selectedIndexPath;
   // NSLog(@"button click event: %d",cell.btnlike.tag);
//    if (clickedButtonIndexPath.row == selectedIndexPath)
//    {
        //cell.btnlike.selected =NO;
        if ([cell.btnlike isSelected])
        {
      
            //cell.btnlike = sender;
            [cell.btnlike setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_good.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            //cell.lblpointtype.text =@"Null";

            cell.btnlike.selected =YES;
            //sender.tag = 0;
            cell.btnlike.titleLabel.text = @"RU";
        }
        else
        {
            //cell.btnlike = sender;
            [cell.btnlike setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_good_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           // sender.tag = 1;
            //cell.lblpointtype.text = @"U";

            cell.btnlike.selected = NO;
            cell.btnlike .titleLabel.text = @"SU";
            
        }
    // [cell.btnlike setSelected:! cell.btnlike.selected];
      //  cell.btnlike = !cell.selected;

   // }
    [self sendDataToServer :@"GET"];
   // cell.lblpointtype.text = [[arry objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath]objectForKey:@"point_type"];

}
=========================tableview load ==============================


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
       cell.lbltitle.text  = [searchresult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        
        [cell.activityloding startAnimating];

    
     //  [cell.btnlike addTarget:self action:@selector(like:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    
    cell.myimage.image = nil; 
   
    
    
    NSDictionary *ar1 = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //  NSLog(@"%@",ar1);
    
    NSString *postimage;
    postimage = [ar1 objectForKey:@"post_image"];
     NSLog(@"%@",postimage);
    str1 = [ar1 objectForKey:@"post_word"];
    // NSLog(@"%@",str1);
    str2 = [ar1 objectForKey:@"post_points"];
    NSString *comment;
    comment = [ar1 objectForKey:@"comment_count"];
   // NSLog(@"comment: = %@",comment);

    cell.btnlike.tag = [indexPath row];

    cell.lbltitle.text = str1;
    cell.lblpoint.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.lblpoint.text = str2;
    
    if(![comment isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        cell.lblcomment.text = comment;
        cell.lblcomment.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblcomment.text = @"0";
    }
    [cell.myimage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“YOUR_LINK_HERE”,[[arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"post_image"]]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil]];
    
        NSString *nul  =[[arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"point_type"];
        if ([nul isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            cell.lblpointtype.text = @"Null";
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lblpointtype.text = @"U";
            [cell.btnlike setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_good_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

    }

    
    return cell;
    
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh i added my code. please review and let me know.

Comment: @JayDhamsaniya, please add complete code for creating cell cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @SanjayMohnani added the code u need .

Answer (score 0):

You can set the buttons tag as indexpath.row when you add button to a cell.

And then you can access selected index path using sender.tag.

Answer (score 0):

When we use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`: cells get reused.

For Instance suppose your table view at once can have show 4 rows, so table view will alloc 4-5 rows(approx), when you scroll upwards your first row go upwards off the screen and the 5th row comes to visible area, similarly 6th, 7th and so on, what table view does in this case, it doesn't alloc the new cells for upcoming visible rows(5th, 6th ...) rather it uses the rows which will go upwards and will be invisible, rows(1st, 2nd so on).

Lets reduce our instance to few rows, lets say we are scrolling upwards and

```
row 1st will be reused for row 6th,
row 2nd will be reused for row 7th,
```

and so on

Suppose each row has a button whose background color is red, tapping on the button changes the corresponding cells button background color to green.

Initially all cells button will have background color as red.
We scroll and go to 6th row, tap it's button, the background color of button will change from red to green and will be reflected on 6th row, we now scroll bottom to see 1st row, as 1st row will reuse 6th row cell so it's button color will be green, thus 1st and 6th row's button will be set to green color.

*And this is the thing which is happening in your case.*

**To resolve above problem** you should keep all the settings for each cell in model, when you create a cell(whether it's newly allocated or reused) set the default properties for each `subview` of cell and than for the corresponding index path access the data fro the data source and set the properties to the respective subviews. Also update the data source for the respective row in button touch events and reload the corresponding row. Doing so will resolve your issue.